# Execute array into DB by Dapper

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, dapper

If `string Subject = "Hello";` and `int[] Category = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };`
How can i insert above variables into DB with one execute session? (i'm using Dapper)

My sql stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TKNewTicket]
        @Subject nvarchar(max),
        @Category int
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @ObjectID [int]
        INSERT INTO dbo.TKTickets(Subject) VALUES (@Subject)
        SET @ObjectID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        INSERT INTO dbo.TKTicketCategory(TicketId, CategoryId) VALUES(@ObjectID, @Category)
    END
    GO
```

My Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TKTickets] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [Subject] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL, )


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TKTicketCategory] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [TicketId] INT NULL,
    [CategoryId] INT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TKTicketCategory_TKTickets] FOREIGN KEY ([TicketId]) REFERENCES [TKTickets]([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TKTicketCategory_TKCategories] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryId]) REFERENCES [TKCategories]([Id]), )
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.

```
public static void NewTicket(string Subject, int[] Categories)
        {
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(SqlDataAccess.GetConnectionString()))
            {
                string sql = @"dbo.InsertNewTicket @Subject";

                var ObjectId = cnn.Query<int>(sql, new { Subject = Subject }).Single();

                foreach(int Category in Categories)
                {
                    sql = @"InsertNewTicketCategory @TicketId, @CategoryId";

                    cnn.Query(sql, new { TicketId = ObjectId, CategoryId = Category });
                }

            }
        }
```